# Replace all words that start with @ by another word

Tags: notepad++, regex

So, basicly, I need to edit something like this:

```
@john TEST TEST TEST

@andrew EXAMPLE EXAMPLE

@geady JK JK JK
```

and I need to replace all of them to get like this:

```
@replaced TEST TEST TEST

@replaced EXAMPLE EXAMPLE

@replaced JK JK JK
```

How can I achieve this with notepad++? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `@\w+`
- Replace with: `@replaced`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
@       # literally
\w+     # 1 or more word character (i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9_])
           You may use \S+ if you want to match any character that is not a space
```

**Result for given example:**

```
@replaced TEST TEST TEST

@replaced EXAMPLE EXAMPLE

@replaced JK JK JK
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although it didn't worked 100% for me...

I'm using:

Find what: @\S+

Replace with: @replaced\L$0

And I get: @replaced@john TEST TEST TEST

Comment: @pedroribeiro98: Could you show some cases that don't work?

Comment: I just edit my comment above @Toto. Thanks for the help

Comment: @pedroribeiro98: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1381347/edit) and add some test cases with expected result.

Comment: I think it's clear, I want to replace the word that starts with @, so instead of getting [@john] , I get [@replaced] , but with your solution, I'm getting [@replaced@john]

Comment: Fixed by using @replaced , I'm dumb :( Thanks for the help

Comment: @pedroribeiro98: Sorry there was a typo in my answer ;(